# Optimizar consulta en Django para Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

El proyecto usa MySql como motor de base de datos, se me hace lenta al mostrar una de todos los registros de una tabla que contiene unos 1500 registros.

Para enviar los datos a la plantilla uso una ListView en la vista y en la plantilla uso un Datatables para mostrar los datos.

```
class ConductorBackendListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    permission_required = 'datos.gestionar'
    model = Conductor
    template_name = 'datos/conductor_backend_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'conductores'
    #paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Conductor.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
```

La opción que mejor funciona es poniendole una paginación, que como veis luego he comentado en el código, ya que intento utilizar las ventajas del [datatables](https://datatables.net/)
Pero el resultado es que la vista tarda unos 5 segundos en cargarse completamente usando el Datatables, mientras que si uso la paginación de django tarda milisegundos, pero no puedo usar las funciones de ordenar y buscar que me ofrece el Datatables.

Añado tambien la parte de conductor_backend_list.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tabla-conductores-backend').DataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 8},

  ]
  ,
  "language":{
       "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
       "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
             "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
             "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
             "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
             "search" : "Búsqueda",
             "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
             "Processing": "Procesando...",
             "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
             "paginate": {
     "previous": "Anterior",
     "next": "Siguiente", 
     }
      } 
});
            } );
</script>
<table id="tabla-conductores-backend" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Frontend</th>
            <th>Backend</th>
            <th>Baja</th>
      <th style="text-align:center">Modificar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
{% if conductores %}
{% for conductor in conductores %}
      <tr>
                <td>{{ conductor.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ conductor.Nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ conductor.Apellidos }}</td>
                <td>{{ conductor.Empresa }}</td>
                <td>{{ conductor.Usuario }}</td>
                <td>{{ conductor.SituacionFrontend }}</td>
                <td>{{ conductor.SituacionBackend }}</td>
                <td>{{ conductor.Baja }}</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="{% url 'datos.editar_conductor_backend' pk=conductor.pk %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"</span> </a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

¿Como podría mejorar este rendimiento?
¿Alguna otra idea?, quizás esté enfocandolo mal

¡Gracias!

Comment: Datatables suele ofrecer un mejor rendimiento cuando en lugar de crear la DataTable desde un objeto table del DOM coge los datos JSON desde el servidor. Planteate hacer una prueba sirviendo los datos desde una API Rest con django-rest-framework por ejemplo. Pegar el código que usas en cliente también puede ser de ayuda

Comment: Para optimización, lo mejor es lo que te recomienda @FranciscoPuga, página con rest-framework, también podrías mejorar la consulta inicial, trayendo los datos de otras tablas usando `select_related` para evitar que demore consultando en el render.

Comment: Estoy probando que el DataTable reciba los datos por JSON, y ciertamente es mucho más rapido, de momento no ha sido necesario instalar el el django-rest-framework, he pasado el resultado de la consulta a JSON y funciona bien. Ahora estoy con algún detalle adicional que implica este cambio.

Comment: Que lenguaje de P. es, python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo los consejos de @FranciscoPuga y @GermanAlzate, muchas gracias por cierto, he realizado cambios para que el DataTable reciba los datos vía Json.

La mejoría ha sido muy sustancial ya que hemos pasado de unos 5 segundos de carga a poco mas de 300ms

De momento no he utilizado django-rest-framework y se seguramente esta solución pueda mejorarse ...

views.py

```
def conductoresJson(request):
    Conductores = Conductor.objects.values('pk','Nombre','Apellidos','Empresa__Nombre','Usuario__username','SituacionFrontend','SituacionBackend','Baja').all().order_by('-pk')
    datosJson = json.dumps(list(Conductores))
    return HttpResponse("""{"data":"""+datosJson+"}" , content_type='application/json')


def vistaConductoresJson(request):
    return render(request, 'datos/conductor_backend_list_json.html')
```

conductor_backend_list_json.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var tabla = $('#tabla-conductores-backend-json').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": " {% url 'datos.conductoresJson' %}",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "language":{
                        "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
                        "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
            "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "search" : "Búsqueda",
            "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
            "Processing": "Procesando...",
            "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
            "paginate": {
                                "previous": "Anterior",
                                "next": "Siguiente", 
                        }
                }, 
                columns: [
                        { data:'pk' },
                        { data:'Nombre'},
                        { data:'Apellidos'},
                        { data:'Empresa__Nombre'},
                        { data:'Usuario__username'},
                        { data:'SituacionFrontend'},
                        { data:'SituacionBackend'},
                        { data:'Baja'},
                        { data : null, defaultContent : "<center><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'</span></a></center>", orderable:false },
                        ],
    } );
        $('#tabla-conductores-backend-json tbody').on( 'click', 'a', function () {
        var fila = tabla.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                window.location.href = "/datos/editar-conductor-backend/"+fila['pk'];
    } );
} );
</script>

<table id="tabla-conductores-backend-json" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Frontend</th>
            <th>Backend</th>
            <th>Baja</th>
      <th style="text-align:center">Modificar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

También deberías de usar el [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) o el [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), esto va a hacer que hagas menos consultas, no has enseñado los modelos pero viendo el values, puedes poner esto(adaptalo a tus modelos)

```
Conductores = Conductor.objects.values('pk', 'Nombre', 'Apellidos', 'Empresa__Nombre',
'Usuario__username', 'SituacionFrontend', 'SituacionBackend', 'Baja'
).select_related('Usuario', 'Empresa').all().order_by('-pk')
```

Comment: Lo he probado, y supongo que debería tener bastantes más registros para notarlo en cuanto al tiempo que tarda en devolver el Json con los datos. Eso si, me SQLite me funciona tal y como lo pones, pero en MySQL me obliga a ponerlo antes el select_related que el values.

Comment: Si disculpa, tiene que ser siempre antes que el values, ya tiene que ser un queryset y devuelve otro, si quierse ver el número de consultas que hace puedes mirarlo así: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556139/get-sql-query-count-during-a-django-shell-session